# Is there way to define optional macros in Apache Freemarker?

Tags: apache, freemarker

Using the macros for the inherited page layout designing. My main webpage layout looks like this

mainlayout.ftl

```
<div>
   <@head/>
   <@body/>
</div>
```

Now the page including mainlayout.ftl looks somewhat like this and may supply head macro

page1.ftl

```
<#include "/mainlayout.ftl"/>
<#macro body>
 ...........
</#macro>
```

Since the maylayout.ftl is expecting @head macro, it throwing error during page rendering.

Is there a way to make @head macro optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an empty head macro in your mainlayout.ftl and you will have to define it in page1.ftl.

mainlayout.ftl

```
<#macro head></#macro>

<div>
   <@head/>
   <@body/>
</div>
```

page1.ftl

```
<#include "/mainlayout.ftl"/>
<#macro body>
 ...........
</#macro>
```